# Facebook Graph API retrieving friends' images

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get all the ids of all my friends along with their profile image.  I'm using `https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=picture&access_token=[myToken]`

I'm getting this returned:

```
{
"data": [
{
"id": "xxx",
"picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/xxx_q.jpg"
}
```

The picture url that returns is for a really small image.  How can I get a larger image?

Comment: Write the response using console.log and see the response in browser, you will see there are number of image sources each with different sizes in api response, you can select the url which returns best picture size for your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

**Recommended**
According to [Doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#pictures) (section "Pictures"), url of profile's photos can be built with the user id

For example, assuming user id is in $id :

```
"http://graph.facebook.com/$id/picture?type=square"
"http://graph.facebook.com/$id/picture?type=small"
"http://graph.facebook.com/$id/picture?type=normal"
"http://graph.facebook.com/$id/picture?type=large"
```

**Hack**

> http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/xxx_`q`.jpg

You can replace the `q` parameter with `s` or `b`
:)

Comment: The examples you gave me require me to have the ids beforehand.  I want to retrieve all the ids and images of all my friends at the same time but want the image a large one.

Comment: You don't need id for hack solution. just loop through response and replace _q with _s.